# How to get direction of a PhysicsBody SKNode in spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I've got an SKNode with an impulse applied. Is there a way to know in every time the direction that it has?

It collides with many bodies, and I want to know which is his direction in real time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 yourPhysicsBody.velocity
```

This should return the velocity CGVector of the physics body at any given time.

Comment: What I want to do is to save direction and velocity to apply to another SKNode in my SKScene.

Comment: this should do it: anotherPhysicsBody.velocity = yourPhysicsBody.velocity

Answer (score 3):

First, get the x and y components of the sprite's velocity

```
let dx = sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dx
let dy = sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dy
```

then compute the direction (in radians) of the sprite

```
let angle = atan2(dy, dx)
```

Optionally, you can change the direction of the sprite to face its motion

```
sprite.zRotation = angle
```

Comment: I don't know if your answer is correct, I've already solved with the other's answer ;) thank you anyway for your support!